# XSLT: displaying multiple data in single template

Tags: xml, xslt

Getting to know XML and XSLT but still Wrestling. I'm still working on the bowling league website and I need to display multiple data with one header...

Here's the code and you'll see what I mean:

```
<TeamScores>
        <TeamScore>
            <Name><![CDATA[AWW 2]]></Name>
            <PlayerScores>
                <PlayerScore>
                    <Name>Dhr. Foubert Guy</Name>
                    <HDC>21</HDC>
                    <HighSerie>599</HighSerie>
                    <HighGame>236</HighGame>
                </PlayerScore>
                <PlayerScore>
                    <Name>Dhr. Goris Swa</Name>
                    <HDC>28</HDC>
                    <HighSerie>545</HighSerie>
                    <HighGame>233</HighGame>
                </PlayerScore>
                <PlayerScore>
                    <Name>Dhr. Korsten Ronny</Name>
                    <HDC>7</HDC>
                    <HighSerie>626</HighSerie>
                    <HighGame>219</HighGame>
                </PlayerScore>
                <PlayerScore>
                    <Name>Dhr. Kortsen David</Name>
                    <HDC>23</HDC>
                    <HighSerie>499</HighSerie>
                    <HighGame>183</HighGame>
                </PlayerScore>
                <PlayerScore>
                    <Name>Dhr. Pauwels Jan</Name>
                    <HDC>26</HDC>
                    <HighSerie>538</HighSerie>
                    <HighGame>204</HighGame>
                </PlayerScore>
                <PlayerScore>
                    <Name>Mvr. Van Steenwinkel Sandra</Name>
                    <HDC>44</HDC>
                    <HighSerie>449</HighSerie>
                    <HighGame>171</HighGame>
                </PlayerScore>
            </PlayerScores>
        </TeamScore>
        <TeamScore>
            <Name><![CDATA[De Candy Pins]]></Name>
            <PlayerScores>
                <PlayerScore>
                    <Name>Dhr. Brusselmans Steven</Name>
                    <Game1>156</Game1>
                    <Game2>157</Game2>
                    <Game3>147</Game3>
                    <Tot>460</Tot>
                    <TotHDC>544</TotHDC>
                    <HDC>28</HDC>
                    <HighSerie>533</HighSerie>
                    <HighGame>204</HighGame>
                </PlayerScore>
                <PlayerScore>
                    <Name>Mvr. Claes Ginne</Name>
                    <HDC>61</HDC>
                    <HighSerie>358</HighSerie>
                    <HighGame>149</HighGame>
                </PlayerScore>
                <PlayerScore>
                    <Name>Dhr. Jurgen Driesen</Name>
                    <Game1>179</Game1>
                    <Game2>214</Game2>
                    <Game3>171</Game3>
                    <Tot>564</Tot>
                    <TotHDC>564</TotHDC>
                    <HDC>0</HDC>
                    <HighSerie>749</HighSerie>
                    <HighGame>269</HighGame>
                </PlayerScore>
                <PlayerScore>
                    <Name>Mvr. Kelders Wanda</Name>
                    <HDC>42</HDC>
                    <HighSerie>521</HighSerie>
                    <HighGame>207</HighGame>
                </PlayerScore>
                <PlayerScore>
                    <Name>Dhr. Schrovens Bart</Name>
                    <HDC>22</HDC>
                    <HighSerie>519</HighSerie>
                    <HighGame>210</HighGame>
                </PlayerScore>
                <PlayerScore>
                    <Name>Dhr. Tielemans Steven</Name>
                    <Game1>154</Game1>
                    <Game2>197</Game2>
                    <Game3>235</Game3>
                    <Tot>586</Tot>
                    <TotHDC>595</TotHDC>
                    <HDC>3</HDC>
                    <HighSerie>671</HighSerie>
                    <HighGame>242</HighGame>
                </PlayerScore>
                <PlayerScore>
                    <Name>Mvr. Van Reeth Natasja</Name>
                    <HDC>52</HDC>
                    <HighSerie>363</HighSerie>
                    <HighGame>129</HighGame>
                </PlayerScore>
                <PlayerScore>
                    <Name>Dhr. Weijten Jeroen</Name>
                    <HDC>7</HDC>
                    <HighSerie>642</HighSerie>
                    <HighGame>232</HighGame>
                </PlayerScore>
            </PlayerScores>
            <Game1>489</Game1>
            <Game2>568</Game2>
            <Game3>553</Game3>
            <Tot>1610</Tot>
            <TotHDC>1703</TotHDC>
        </TeamScore>
        <TeamScore>
```

I managed to display all players with their scores into one table... But I'd like to display the teams they play for as well

This is the XSLT I'm using:

```
<xsl:template match="/leagueScores/TeamScores">
<html>
  <body>
  <h1>Individuele Uitslagen</h1>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>Naam</th>
      <th>G1</th>
      <th>G2</th>
      <th>G3</th>
      <th>TOT S</th>
      <th>TOT H</th>
      <th>HDC</th>
      <th>Hi Serie</th>
      <th>Hi Game</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="TeamScore/PlayerScores/PlayerScore">
    <xsl:if test="Game1 &gt; 0">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Name"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Game1"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Game2"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Game3"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="Tot"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="TotHDC"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="HDC"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="HighSerie"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="HighGame"/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
```

I'm looking for an output like this:

```
"TEAM1"
"PLAYER1"
"PLAYER2"
"PLAYER3"
"TEAM2"
"PLAYER1"
"PLAYER2"
"PLAYER3"
```

... in a table with columns for the games and totals...
So I just want to insert a row for each team in between the correct team's players.

Is this possible?

Comment: Is it possible - certainly. Please edit the question to include the XSLT you've written so far and a sample of the output you're aiming for, and then we can help you debug it.

Comment: Does this help you Ian?

Comment: Would I be right in thinking that the actual team names in your sample are "AWW 2" and "De Candy Pins"?

Comment: @MichaelKay yes that is correct!

Answer (score 0):

You need parent selector:

```
  <td><xsl:value-of select="../../Name"/></td>
```

http://xsltransform.net/6qVRKwf

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a single `for-each` over all the `PlayerScore` elements in one go, I'd approach it with two nested levels

```
<xsl:for-each select="TeamScore">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="9">
      <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <xsl:for-each select="PlayerScores/PlayerScore">
    <!-- ... -->
```

Comment: Well actually, I'd approach it using templates rather than `for-each` but that's beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: could you edit with more code on top and bottom maybe because I can't manage to get it right... Thanks

Comment: @RobbeRousseau my code just replaces your `<xsl:for-each select="TeamScore/PlayerScores/PlayerScore">` tag, and you'll also need to add a second `</xsl:for-each>` just before the `</table>`